# How to add custom slide indicators in an ngb-carousel?

Tags: carousel, ng-bootstrap

I need to show the index of the current showing slide in ngb-carousel. like -

> < 1/10 > or < 2/10 > etc.

Where 1 or 2 is the current slide number and 10 is the total number of slides.

Using ng-bootstrap 2.2.0, I have set showNavigationIndicators to false. But I am unable to figure out how to get the slide indicators in the above format.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Probably you need to wrap it in your own component, and inside of it, just create some *ngFor with your custom indicators, that on click will trigger carousel `select` method